# separate controller for ajax actionresults in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

For ajax calls actionresult I am thinking of two options

1. Place the actionresults in
   controller most suited to their functions
2. Make a separate controller for ajax calls

In second approach i may use separate files to functionally divide the controller and use partial `ajaxcontroller` class in each file. 
Second option may be helpful if there are some actionfilter attributes that i want to apply on actionresults other than the ajax actionresults e.g Authorize attribute may be applied to normal action result. I may use [Ajaxonly](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/ajaxonly-actions-and-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc/) attribute on ajax actionresults to secure them
which option would u prefer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to do that? For me, a controller is tied to a certain model, not a certain type of output format.

```
public ActionResult Users()
{
    var users = _repository.Find(); 
    var viewModel  = Mapper.Map(users); // automapper or similar
    return Request.IsAjax() ? Json(viewModel) : View(viewModel);
}
```

**To answer your update**

It's better to create a `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` that checks if it's a ajax request or a regular request and do the proper authorization. Your controllers should not be aware of how authorization is made.

Comment: All of my controllers inherit from base controller there are certain attributes that are applied on that. These attributes needed on ajax.

Comment: Update your question with specific examples to allow me to give a more accurate answer.